# TeeChart not redrawing after call of Canvas.TextExtent of child Label

Tags: delphi, vcl, teechart, delphi-10.3-rio

I use

Embarcadero® Delphi 10.3 Version 26.0.36039.7899

TeeChart Standard v2020.29.200113 32bit VCL

My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate ServicePack1

I put a TChart on form and then i put a label on TChart.
After first call of Label1.Canvas.TextExtent the Chart stops redrawing. For example after minimizing and maximizing form instead of Chart contents i see the part of background window.

Is it allowed to put a label on TChart?

```
type

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Chart1: TChart;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ASize: TSize;
begin
  ASize := Label1.Canvas.TextExtent(Label1.Caption);
end;
```

After click on Button1 the chart stops redrawing.

UPD:

We migrate from Delphi7 to RAD Studio 10.3. In our project we use custom labels. The paint method is overriden. We draw on canvas of label, and we use Label.Canvas.TextExtent to calculate the size of text.

The parent component of labels is TChart.

The example above works correct in Delphi7, but not in Delphi 10.3.

Comment: The code you've posted will not in any way affect redrawing of the chart (or anything else). It also does nothing that will accomplish anything at all. If you want debugging help, please post an [mcve] that will demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @Ken This code isn't meant to achieve anything useful. It already is a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It is? Ok. *Put a TChart on form and put a label on TChart* and reproduce the issue. I drop a TChart, a TLabel and a TButton on a form and copy/paste that button event into the post and can't produce the issue the poster describes.

Comment: @Ken So say that you can't reproduce. But don't complain that the code doesn't accomplish anything when the user has already done the right thing and cut down from the real problem in the more complex app to a simple example.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: A [mcve] includes the term *reproducible*. If I can follow the post instructions explicitly and the problem doesn't occur, it's clearly not *reproducible* based on the content, which is what I said. Thanks, though.

Comment: Of course I post a minimal reproducible example.
Probobly you can't reproduce the problem because you have other version of RAD Studio or TeeChart or OS?
Did you minimize and maximize window after click button1?
I will add versions in my post.

Comment: However, thanks for the reply. Now I know that the problem is condition-dependent. I will try to reproduce this problem with other versions of TChart or RAD studio.

Comment: It is not valid to use a `TLabel.Canvas` outside of an actual paint operation (ie, inside the `TLabel.Paint()` method). Find another solution. For instance, create a separate `TCanvas`, assign the `TLabel.Font` to the `Canvas.Font`, assign the result of `GetWindowDc(Self.Handle)` to the `Canvas.Handle`, then use `Canvas.TextExtent()`.  Or use the Win32 API `DrawText/Ex()` directly instead.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, thank you very much! Your solution works perfect in test project. I will try to use it in real project.